# How to catch errors that were only logged?

Tags: python, logging, error-handling

#### Main Question

I am using a module that relies on logging instead of raising error messages. How can I catch logged errors from within Python to react to them (without dissecting the log file)?

#### Minimal Example

Suppose `logging_module.py` looks like this:

```
import logging
import random

def foo():
    logger = logging.getLogger("quz")
    if random.choice([True,False]):
        logger.error("Doooom")
```

If this module used exceptions, I could do something like this:

```
from logging_module import foo, Doooom

try:
    foo()
except Doooom:
    bar()
```

Assuming that `logging_module` is written the way it is and I cannot change it, this is impossible. What can I do instead?

#### What I considered so far

I went through the [logging documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html) (though I did not read every word), but the only way to access what is logged seems to be dissecting the actual log, which seems overly tedious to me (but I may misunderstand this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a filter to the logger that the module uses to inspect every log. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html#filter-objects) has this to say on using filters for something like that:

> Although filters are used primarily to filter records based on more
>   sophisticated criteria than levels, they get to see every record which
>   is processed by the handler or logger they’re attached to: this can be
>   useful if you want to do things like counting how many records were
>   processed by a particular logger or handler

The code below assumes that you are using the `logging_module` that you showed in the question and tries to emulate what the try-except does: that is, when an error happens inside a call of `foo` the function `bar` is called.

```
import logging

from logging_module import foo

def bar():
    print('error was logged')

def filt(r):
    if r.levelno == logging.ERROR:
        bar()
    return True

logger = logging.getLogger('quz')
logger.addFilter(filt)

foo() # bar will be called if this logs an error
```